# Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter does not write data to a file

Tags: file, spring-batch, filewriter

I am new to Spring Batch application. I am trying to use `FlatFileItemWriter` to write the data into a file. Challenge is application is creating the file on a given path, but, now writing the actual content into it.

Following are details related to code:

`List<String> dataFileList :` **This list contains the data that I want to write to a file**

```
FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("C:\\Desktop\\test"));
writer.open(new ExecutionContext());
writer.setLineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>());
writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
writer.write(dataFileList);
writer.close();
```

This is just generating the file at proper place but contents are not getting written into the file.

Am I missing something? Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems we need to close the stream otherwise the content won't flush

Comment: I did close().. but still contents are not getting written

Comment: Is `dataFileList` filled with data? because I tested your code with SB 4.0 and 2.2.6 and file is correctly filled with test data (`dataFileList` is filled with integer from 0 to 500000 converted to String)

Comment: What about your reader can you post code for that

Comment: How is your dataFileList populated?

Comment: Where are you running this code? Haven't you defined any Bean for it?

Comment: Put full code please

Comment: I have a same problem... @Saurabh Deshpande, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a proper way to use Spring Batch Writer and writer data. You need to declare bean of Writer first.

- Define Job Bean
- Define Step Bean
- Use your Writer bean in Step

Have a look at following examples:

https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-batch-examples/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/net/petrikainulainen/springbatch/csv/in/CsvFileToDatabaseJobConfig.java

https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to force a sync to disk.  From the docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html,

```
setForceSync

public void setForceSync(boolean forceSync)

Flag to indicate that changes should be force-synced to disk on flush. Defaults to false, which means that even with a local disk changes could be lost if the OS crashes in between a write and a cache flush. Setting to true may result in slower performance for usage patterns involving many frequent writes.

Parameters:
    forceSync - the flag value to set
```